# How to fix the Javascript in the following html?

Tags: javascript

The buttons and 'check answer' are not working. This message shows in the console:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fooolghllnmhmmndgjiamiiodkpenpbb/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Hope you guys can help me fix this?

The html follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trivia!</title>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContenLoaded', function() {
        let correct = document.querySelector('.correct');
        correct.addEventListener('click', function() {
          correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
        });

        let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrect');
        for (let i = 0; i < incorrects.length; i++) {
          incorrects[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            incorrects[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.querySelector('#feedback1').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
          });
        }

        document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function() {
          let input = document.querySelector('input');
          if (input.value === 'Switzerland') {
            input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
          } else {
            input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.querySelector('#feedback2').innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
        <hr>
        <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
        <h3>What is the approximate ratio of people to sheep in New Zealand?</h3>
        <button class="incorrect">6 people per 1 sheep</button>
        <button class="incorrect">3 people per 1 sheep</button>
        <button class="incorrect">1 person per 1 sheep</button>
        <button class="incorrect">1 person per 3 sheep</button>
        <button class="correct">1 person per 6 sheep</button>
        <p id="feedback1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
        <hr>
        <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
        <h3>In which country is it illegal to own only one guinea pig, as a lone guinea pig might get lonely?</h3>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button id="check">Check Answer</button>

        <p id="feedback2"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a browser plugin involved. Try disabling your plugins and refresh your page.

Comment: The error you provided does not indicate that the javascript is not working. All it's saying is the source map for an extension isn't being found, which wouldn't prevent the JS on your page from running. It's more of a notice than anything.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in your code

Comment: A simple Google search reveals that `fooolghllnmhmmndgjiamiiodkpenpbb` corresponds to a "NordPass" Chrome extension - why do you care if an extension in your browser throws console errors? How is it at all related to your code you've included here?

Comment: I tried disabling the plugins. The buttons are still not working!

Comment: If the buttons are not working, please edit this into the question itself.  Thanks

Comment: @esqew I am very new to coding. When I run the html, the buttons don't work. So, I checked the console in the developer tool and found this message. Any idea how to make the buttons work?

Comment: @Murad Your code has a typo. It's first listening for an event `DOMContenLoaded`, which doesn't exist. Seems you meant to listen for `DOMContentLoaded`, perhaps? After fixing this, seems like your code works as you intended. If you aren't already I would suggest using a solid IDE which will sometimes alert you to mistakes like this, especially one specialized for HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: @esqew Incredible!!! It worked!!!! You are the MAN! I am so much grateful; I literally spent hours on this! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @esqew  --  perhaps 'promote' your code to an answer, then OP -- Murad  -- could mark it as correct.  Thanks

Comment: @JosephDoggie Definitely not - this question should be closed as being a typographical error, per standard Stack Overflow etiquette. I've voted to close as such. [Relevant Meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: @esqew Shall I have to do anything to close it?

Comment: @Murad I don't believe you'll have the option - once enough high-rep users come by and vote to close for the same reason, it will take care of itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Really appreciate all your comments!

Comment: @esqew Ok! Thanks!